# Can another SQL Server function like YEAR() be used within a Group By?

Tags: sql, function

Is there another possibility to use a function inside a group by apart from Year()?

I have been searching although I would like to know if there are other functions as well which can be used.

I know aggregate functions are not a possibility to use.

I have this example:

```
Select year(orderDate) as year, ShippingCountry, Count(orderId) as Quantity
From Orders
Group By Year(OrderDate), ShippingCountry
Order By Year
```

Comment: Which is it, mysql or swl-server?  I don't see how function or ssms are valid tags

Comment: Yes. Expressions used in `GROUP BY` terms can be complex.

Answer (score 0):

Other date/time functions can be used as well such as `date_trunc()`.
Some more specific functions related to the `group by` clause are `cube()` `rollup()` & `grouping sets()`. More info on the intricacies of those functions described [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6315/group-by-in-sql-server-with-cube-rollup-and-grouping-sets-examples/)